# Como grabar datos en un archivo text haciendo clic

Tags: python

Hola soy novato en el mundo de la programación en python, tengo el siguiente código me gustaría saber como podría modificarlo para hacer que un clic me lo guarde en un archivo txt y otro no. El código es el siguiente:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
from matplotlib.widgets import Cursor, Button  
from numpy import random

x, y = random.rand(2, 100)  
fig, ax = plt.subplots()  
p, = plt.plot(x, y, 'o')

cursor = Cursor(ax, horizOn=True, vertOn=True, color='red', 
linewidth=1.0)  
def onclick(event):    
    x1, y1 = event.xdata, event.ydata  
    print(x1,y1)  
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)

plt.show()
```

Comment: A ver si entiendo, quieres que un click se guarde y el otro no.? basicamente guardar 1 de cada 2 clicks.?

Comment: Si, mi estimado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes manejar una variable donde sepas si es el click a ignorar o a guardar, en mi caso prefiero usar un contador y definir si es par o impar (usando `%` modulo), pero podrias usar un simple boolean para true o false. algo así:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
from matplotlib.widgets import Cursor, Button  
from numpy import random
clicks = 0
x, y = random.rand(2, 100)  
fig, ax = plt.subplots()  
p, = plt.plot(x, y, 'o')


cursor = Cursor(ax, horizOn=True, vertOn=True, color='red', linewidth=1.0)  

def onclick(event):    
    x1, y1 = event.xdata, event.ydata  
    global clicks
    if clicks % 2 == 0:
        print(x1,y1)
        f = open("clicks.txt","a+")
        f.write("X:"+str(x1)+" Y:"+str(y1))
        f.close()
    clicks=clicks+1
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)

plt.show()
```

Espero te ayude.

Comment: Para if clicks % 2 == 0: me sale en el terminal: IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: No sera que global clicks habra que declararlo?

Comment: Ya esta declarado arriba en la linea 4.

Comment: El error que tienes es de identación, verifica que este bien identado el codigoi.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!