# ¿Cómo puedo obtener la hora haciendo click en una imagen?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hola soy nuevo programando en Python, tengo un problema, estoy trabajando con ploteos en archivos .mat y deseo obtener los valores de fecha y hora que estan en el eje x haciendo click sobre este plot. Mi problema es que necesito guardar en un archivo de texto los valores impresos en la terminal al momento de haber hecho click, pero estos valores obtenidos, son diferentes a los valores mostrados en el plot.
¿Alguna idea de lo que esta pasando?

[En la imagen se puede observar el plot al lado izquierdo y la terminal al lado derecho con los valores impresos en ella al momento de haber hecho click.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trRNa.png)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pylab
import scipy.io as sio
import scipy.signal as sg
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime
from matplotlib.dates import num2date, date2num, hours
import os,sys,string
from tkinter import filedialog 
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
import matplotlib
import math 
from matplotlib.widgets import Cursor, Button
from numpy import random
import pylab
clicks = 1 
path = 'C:/Users/Hola/Documents/Descargas/'

files = []
for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:

        if ".mat" in file:
            files.sort()
            files.append(os.path.join(r, file))


for i in range(len(files)):
    est = 'NPM'

    file = files[i]
    plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 8,5
    plt.rcParams['figure.autolayout'] = False
    plt.rcParams['font.size']=10
    figure, ax = plt.subplots()

    mat_contents0 = sio.loadmat(file)


    channel_sampling_freq0 = mat_contents0['Fs']
    data_amp               = mat_contents0['data']  
  #callsign0              = filename0[14:17]
    adc_channel0           = mat_contents0['adc_channel_number']
    start_day0             = mat_contents0['start_day']
    start_minute0          = mat_contents0['start_minute']
    start_month0           = mat_contents0['start_month']
    start_hour0            = mat_contents0['start_hour']
    start_second0          = mat_contents0['start_second']
    start_year0            = mat_contents0['start_year']
    station_name0          = mat_contents0['station_name']
    startdate0             = dt.datetime(start_year0,start_month0,start_day0,start_hour0,start_minute0,start_second0)
    time0                  = pd.date_range(str(startdate0), periods=len(data_amp),
                                     freq=str(channel_sampling_freq0)[2:3]+' s')

    df0 = pd.DataFrame(data_amp  , index=time0,columns=['amp'])
    df0_integrated = df0.resample('10 s').mean ()   

    pd.plotting.register_matplotlib_converters()
    ax.plot(df0_integrated.index, 20*np.log10(df0_integrated.amp),'red',lw=1)  

    ax.set_ylabel('VLF Ampl (dB)')
    ax.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(True)
    ax.grid( ls='--')

     ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0,40,10))

     figure.subplots_adjust(hspace=.0100,wspace=0.000)

    x, y = random.rand(2, 100)

    cursor = Cursor(ax,
                    horizOn = True, 
                    vertOn = True, 
                    linewidth = 1
                )
    def onclick(event):
        x = event.xdata

        global clicks
        if clicks % 2 == 0:
            print(x)

            file = open("C:/Users/Hola/Documents/Descargas/Prueba.txt","a")
            file.write("   ")
            file.write("   "+str(x)+"   ")
            file.write("   ")
            file.close()

        clicks = clicks + 1 

    figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)

    plt.show()
```

Comment: Te servirá ésto.? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/315219/como-grabar-datos-en-un-archivo-text-haciendo-clic/315233#315233

Comment: Podrías evaluar cual seria el resultado esperado.?

Comment: @JhoubertRincon de esa pregunta es que he podido extraer el código si, pero mi problema es que en el ploteo en el eje x se muetra la hora, lo que ocurre es que cuando yo clickeo sobre cualquier parte del gráfico, los valores impresos en la terminal son diferentes a los valores en el eje x, por ejemplo si yo clickeo en las 11:02, en la terminal me sale 733773.62, ese es mi problema principal de esta pregunta, estoy trabajando con Pandas paras las horas, se puede ver en el código fuente, podrias decirme por que estos valores son diferentes.

Comment: Al hacer dos clicks estas obteniendo 1 solo registro.?

Comment: Si pero el que registra es el ultimo

Comment: Así es, sólo elimina el if de `if clicks % 2 == 0:` para que guarde todos los clicks.

Comment: No lo puedo eliminar, por que lo necesito para trabajar, para poder hacer acercamientos al ploteo, lo necesito. Como te digo los valores del ploteo son distintos a los valores impresos al terminal, como sale en la imagen que publique, ese es mi unico problema

Comment: Creo que necesito algun código para que en la terminal salga el valor al que he hecho click

Comment: Se entiende mi problema?

Comment: Cómo puedo transformar esos valores?

Comment: La coordenada no es el valor que te sale en el print(x)?

Comment: Quisiera poder ejecutar el código, pero no tengo algún .mat. podrías subir uno.?

Comment: @JhoubertRincon, si pero con ese print(x) es el que me imprime un valor no desaeado en la terminal

Comment: Súbelo a algún servicio de cloud y pon el link.

Comment: No estoy seguro si sea permitido colocar información personal en el sitio (fuera del perfil), en todo caso puedes subirlo a cualquier servicio de alojamiento, editar la pregúnta y dejar el link con el archivo de ejemplo.

Comment: En mi perfil puedes encontrar un correo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rocker, los datos si son reales, solo que los números del plot son muy cortos y solo cambia por algunos decimales (para X), para Y si puedes observar el valor mas claro.

Puedes comprobarlo mostrando los datos del evento haciendo lo siguiente:

```
def onclick(event):
    x = event.xdata
    y = event.ydata        
    print(event)
    print(x,y)
```

Sí por otra parte deseas ver las coordenadas dentro de la ventana puedes verlos en los siguientes atributos(PD: no es la coordenada dentro del .mat, sino de la ventana del matplotlib):

```
    print(event.y)
    print(event.x)
```

EDIT:

El valor de event.xdata es una fecha convertida a número por el matplotlib para crear la gráfica precisa, para ver la fecha exacta debes usar el metodo `num2date` de la clase dates de matplotlib. quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
def onclick(event):
    x = event.xdata
    y = event.ydata
    xdate=matplotlib.dates.num2date(x)
    print(x) # FECHA EN NÚMERO CONVERTIDA POR MATPLOTLIB.
    print(xdate) # FECHA LEGIBLE.
```

Espero te sea útil, saludos.

Comment: Pero y si quiero ver las coordenadas .mat como hago?

Comment: Lo que necesito visualizar son los datos 01 11:29 por ejemplo que aparecen en el eje x, ese es mi único problema, las coordenadas del matplotlib, se tienen que transformar?

Comment: O sea que los decimales que aparecen en el eje x son las coordenadas del matplotlib pero lo que no entiendo, no se como que hacer para cambiar los códigos.

Comment: Qué codigos necesitas cambiar.? Necesitas mostrar la hora en la que se hizo click, no.?

Comment: Si, por qué los valores en el eje x muestran la hora

Comment: Tengo que cambiar algo en el print(x)?

Comment: Ahora entiendo que es lo que necesitas, dame un momento.

Comment: Matpltolib convierte la fecha en un número para graficarlo de manera precisa. lo que debes hacer es convertir el valor de X a fecha con la clase dates de matplotlib. `print(matplotlib.dates.num2date(x))`, editaré la respuesta.